# How is putting the lambda expression after the parameters on a mapTo call legal syntax?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I found a piece of code I do not understand.

I am transforming a `JSONArray` into a `List`.
Kotlin provides the function `mapTo` in it's `stdlib`([link](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html))

> **mapTo**
>
> ```
> inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapTo(
>     destination: C, 
>     transform: (T) -> R
> ): C (source)
> ```
>
> Applies the given transform function to each element of the original collection and appends the results to the given destination.

This functions has 2 parameters and can be used like this (as expected):

```
(0..jsonArray.length() - 1).mapTo(targetList, {it -> jsonArray[it].toString()})
```

But apparently this is also valid syntax (not expected):

```
(0..jsonArray.length()-1).mapTo(targetList) {it -> jsonArray[it].toString()}
```

As you can see, the function parameters end after `outputList` and the lambda expression is just put at the end of the function call.

---

Furthermore this is legal (as expected):

```
val transformation = {it : Int -> jsonArray[it].toString()}
(0..jsonArray.length()-1).mapTo(targetList, transformation)
```

but this is not (???):

```
val transformation = {it : Int -> jsonArray[it].toString()}
(0..jsonArray.length()-1).mapTo(targetList) transformation
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions):

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a
>   function is a function, and you're passing **a lambda expression** as the
>   corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses:
>
> ```
> lock (lock) {
>     sharedResource.operation()
> }
> ```
>
> Another example of a higher-order function would be map():
>
> ```
> fun <T, R> List<T>.map(transform: (T) -> R): List<R> {
>     val result = arrayListOf<R>()
>     for (item in this)
>         result.add(transform(item))
>     return result
> }
> ```
>
> This function can be called as follows:
>
> ```
> val doubled = ints.map { it -> it * 2 }
> ```
>
> Note that the parentheses in a call can be omitted entirely if the
>   lambda is the only argument to that call.

The documentation states clearly that for the above to work the last argument must be lambda expression and not a variable of matching type.

Comment: I swear, I have read this page in the docs 20 times, but somehow my brain always skipped that part. Thank you!

Comment: *What's not clear from the documentation is that the parameter must be a lambda literal.* **Not really, since it says** *... is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument,...*

Comment: I think this is a good approach, as the expression in `{ }` looks more natural than just a `transform` jammed to the end of the call

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this convention?

Comment: @krupal.agile random preferences? I do like it though.

Comment: why does the android studio IDE want you to do it so bad?

Comment: @krupal.agile I agree that it's a little weird, but seemingly it's a common coding practice to put a lambda as the last argument (either for a callback or a utility function used by the called function) and it really does make the code look cleaner without those }) instances, and in case of callbacks it captures the intended code flow well (in its own way).

Comment: Updated documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas